# Running a Django 1.4-based app on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm working on a Django 1.4-based social networking website as a personal project. I'm considering hosting it at Google App Engine; however, I've read that its non-relational database engine doesn't support joins.

How does that affect me, i.e. are there any I should take for make my site work on GAE, or does Django work fully out of the box?

My site relies on numerous third-party Django apps, including [django-generic-m2m](https://github.com/coleifer/django-generic-m2m). Would I even need it on Google's DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to apply for access to [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/), which apparently [supports django](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/django) running on GAE.

Comment: I considered it; however, their application form implies enterprise-scale applications.

Comment: I don't know what the pricing is going to be like when it is generally available, but I have a couple extremely small django applications running on Google Cloud SQL and I really like it. My Django app doesn't need anything special to run, just configure the database like the docs say.

Comment: As for pricing - it starts 12th June, according to this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing I guess also on that day the invite-only access will be changed to open, however I cannot find info about it.

Comment: @PawelMarkowski Yup, so I gave up on Cloud SQL, and couldn't get `django-nonrel` to work as I wanted, either - it's still a young project, after all. I'm currently trying out http://www.pythonanywhere.com - which has a free plan with MySQL out of the box.